# pandas- drop column with duplicated header after performing 'asfreq'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have data like

```
DATE      COUNT
2018-01-01   1
2018-01-02   1
2018-01-06   1
2018-01-07   1
```

I use `df=df.asfreq('D', fill_value=0)` to fill in the missing dates:

```
           DATE            COUNT
DATE 
2018-01-01   2018-01-01     1
2018-01-02   2018-01-02     1
2018-01-03                  0
2018-01-04                  0
2018-01-05                  0
2018-01-06  2018-01-06      1
2018-01-07  2018-01-07      1
```

How would I delete the original `DATE` featuring missing dates?

Comment: You can use `df.drop("DATE", axis=1)`. This will leave the `index` `DATE` in place.

Comment: I assumed this question was a duplicate but couldn't find one. Pandas docs here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html

Comment: `df.set_index('DATE').asfreq('D', fill_value=0)`, won't have the duplicate column.  Do you set your index to `DATE` somewhere without dropping the column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the index is datetime, you could also resample by mean to the original sample rate of this dataframe. This would keep the original data and put NaNs when data is missing.

```
df = df.resample('D').mean()
```

If you want to fill the missing date's with 0's you can do:

```
df = df.resample('D').mean().fillna(0)
```